# What is the reason of pixelation on Sony ILCE-7?

Tags: sony, viewfinder, live-view, sony-alpha, viewfinder-indicators

When I look at the camera display or through the viewfinder of Sony A7 in shooting mode, it shows me a pixelated picture. However all numbers (like ISO, shutter speed etc.) and interface elements are sharp and smooth. Only the image is pixelated. Why?

How Sony A7 shows the picture in shooting mode:

[image: Pixelated image in viewfinder Sony A7]

How the picture should look like:
[image: Normal image (public domain photograph from Flickr)]

Comment: What are your settings in `Menu - Setup - Display Quality`?

Comment: @Andrew it was set to "Standard". By changing it to "High", the picture became more detailed, however pixelation hasn't totally disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

What you are demonstrating in your pictures is more of a case of "aliasing" than pixelation. If that's what you mean (the perception that the picture is composed of straight lines rather than proper curves), it happens because of the real time picture resize algorithms the camera uses to display the 24MP images coming from the sensor on the 2MP EVF, and it is perfectly normal.

There are antialiasing algorithms to deal with that but I guess Sony has chosen to keep the EVF images sharp but aliased vs. a bit softer but antialiased. Display information do not get affected by that because they are generated upfront for the resolution of your EVF.

Personally, I find the aliasing effect useful when shooting with manual lenses because it is most visible around the edges and can be used as a means of confirming focus without even turning on focus peaking.